# Wicket Modal Render on show(target)

Tags: java, ajax, asynchronous, wicket

I have a problem with Wicket Modal Window. I have a Modal Window does a UNIREST call to an external service. The response is used to populate a list. The list is used by a DropDownChoice. The problem is the Wicket Modal Window is inside a repeater, so could happen a page does houndreds of calls to create the modals before the contenitor page is rendered.

```
class Page{
   ListView listView = new ListView(wicket:id, list){
   @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Article> item) {
           ModalWindow modal = new Modal(){
           //the modal inside the constructor do the call to render the DropDownChoice 
           //and so before the entire page is rendered houndreds of call are done
           }
        }
    }   
}
```

On the browser side this is very bad and make the system very very slow. There is a method to do the call only at the click time, when the modal is effectively shown? There is a method to do asynchronous call to populate the list without Wicket thrown an exception?

I thought to initialize the list with an empty List and at the click time do the CALL and re-render the modal via AJAX. Is it possible? Is it a good way to do so?

Comment: You should only create one `ModalWindow` per page and instead when you want to show one use the `setContent(Component component)` method to create and set the content of that `ModalWindow` before calling the `show` method to display it. Are you currently already creating all the contents in your page constructor?

Comment: it seems to work! Thanks

Comment: Actually the correct way is to have only one `ModalWindow` with its content per page and only change its model before calling the `show` method. I can put together an answer which demonstrates this approach if you want to give it a try.

Comment: The solution above already works. Thanks for the answer